# What is the name of this grammatical construct: a sentence has two endings?

Tags: syntax, terminology

Consider the following sentence:

> Local Man Loses Pants, Life; Beaver Rescue Falls Short

I've seen this named before where a sentence has two endings but I've been unable to find it on any grammar or linguistics websites.

Comment: Often called [syllepsis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeugma#Syllepsis).

Comment: And sometimes a [zeugma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeugma).

Comment: Thanks! Syllepsis / Zeugma is exactly what I've been trying to find.

Comment: While Greek names inevitably falute higher than mere English ones, what this really is is _Headlinese_. I.e, it's a characteristic set of journalistic tics (like leaving out _and_ and substituting a comma) that Anglophone editors have come to depend on to save characters in headlines. This is not grammar; this is typography.

Comment: Everyone: Please answer using the *Answers field*. This question will remain unanswered now, unless @Doitle keeps coming back here to accept an answer.

Comment: This particular example is also a *joke*, in that [it's from an episode of the Simpsons](http://www.simpsoncrazy.com/content/lists/newspaper/news_094.jpg). Not that it makes the question any less legitimate - however, humor often contains linguistic play outside the bounds of normal discourse.

Comment: Good point, Mark. Plus, there's nothing sacrosanct about Official Answers. Text is text, and it's all searchable.

Comment: @jlawler: He says "where a sentence has two endings": it's not entirely clear what he means, but it is probably more specific than headlinese.

Comment: I think he means two direct objects without a conjunction. That clearly isn't normal English grammar; it's headlinese. One has to be pretty inventive answering questions here (as in class) because people often don't know exactly how to talk about what's bugging them, and often focus on something exterior to the real issue.

Comment: @jlawler, of course “Headlinese” is grammar, too.

Answer (score 1):

A semicolon alone can be used to coordinate two main clauses; this signals a closer relationship between two independent clauses. Some refer to this stylistic device as the Semicolon Alone Method.

Quoted from http://dictionary.reference.com/writing/styleguide/punctuation.html :

> Semicolon (;)
>    ... Punctuation sometimes regarded as a weak period or strong comma and used in ways similar to periods and commas. A semicolon can mark the end of a clause and indicate that a clause following is closely related to the previous clause. ... 
>   Separates (but also links) independent clauses in place of a coordinating conjunction or ellipsis, e.g. The package was due last week; it arrived today.

The rhetorical figure of leaving out conjunctions (in this case 'and' before 'Life') is called asyndeton, or asyndetic listing.